# NLog replaces parameters out of order when using String.Format style

Tags: .net, logging, nlog, asp.net-core-logging

I'm new to NLog and had some confusing output so I ran a test.

```
_logger.LogInformation(string.Format("{2} {1} {0}", "broken", "nlog", "is"));
_logger.LogInformation("{2} {1} {0}", "broken", "nlog", "is");
```

Which resulted in:

```
is nlog broken
broken nlog is
```

Is NLog not expected to work just like String.Format when using String.Format style replacements?

It appears to replace the values in order without regard to the number. I did try a test with `"{0} {0} {0}"` as the format string and it didn't get logged which leads me to believe it does pay some level of attention to the values. It also leads me to believe that NLog doesn't pass off the handling to `String.Format` because String.Format will happily replace each of those with the first argument.

In case it matters, we are using NLog to write to SQL Server.

Comment: You are using Microsoft Extension Logging (MEL) AND NLog. When you call `LogInformation` then you activate MEL message-parser. It doesn't allow you to reorder message-arguements like string.Format does.

Comment: NLog.Extension.Logging can be configured to take over. But it has a performance hit. Because it will use the MEL-message-parser and then NLog-message-parser (Because NLog is at the end of the chain). Set ParseMessageTemplates=true in https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/NLog-LoggerProvider-Options

Comment: Another alternative is to skip MEL ILogger and just use NLog Logger directly.

Comment: Sorry for "stealing" your answers Rolf. I prefer having answered questions on Stackoverflow O:)

Comment: @Steve Not my downvote, but I think your question is a bit influenced by assumptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Rolf mentioned, when using Microsoft Extension Logging, the parsing is done by Microsoft Extension Logging. (by default because of performance)

Microsoft Extension Logging has no support for string-formatted message but only structured message. So `{2} {1}` and `{0}` will be parsed as names (from left to right)

It would be more logical to log this:

```
_logger.LogInformation("User {User} orders {OrderId}", username, order.Id);
```

If you really like string-formatted messages then you could do:

1. Use NLog directly,

   ```cs
   var logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
   logger.Info("User {1} orders {0}", order.Id, username);
   ```
2. Or, enable "ParseMessageTemplates" in NLogProviderOptions, see https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/NLog-LoggerProvider-Options

Comment: Thank you. Like I said, I'm new to NLog. I didn't realize something else handled the parsing. I'll just switch everything over to using names. I guess the fact that it mostly looks like it works the same as string.format made me thing it was expected to work the same.

Comment: No problem. It's a good question as I think this isn't (easy) to find in the docs.